# How to Add Encryption to Outlook Message Ribbon

Tags: microsoft-outlook, encryption

I want to reply to a message in Outlook and set the encryption option but the encryption option does not show up on the ribbon when replying to an email message within the client screen.
[image]

The encryption option shows up on the ribbon if you "Pop Out" the reply message.
[image]

I tried to add the Encryption command to the ribbon that is displayed when replying to a message from within the outlook but the command is not listed when I select "All commands".
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as you know, this option wouldn't display in main ribbion, according to my tests, it could only display in Message ribbion like below, which means we could only manage it in this view and there may be no option to change it.
[image]